# I am looking how to Go Back in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for the keyboard shortcut for Going Back (to last screen) using the iOS Simulator.

I have tried searching, I didn't find anything.

Comment: There is no such shortcut for xcode simulator.If you want to go to home screen you can use cmd+shft+H

Comment: Do we have any solution yet

Comment: It is ridiculous that there is still no way to do this in 2021

Comment: Yeah until now 2022 same issue

Comment: @yogi-arif-widodo  Can you elaborate?  What is wrong with the answer I provided below?  I cannot help you if you do not elaborate.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia the question is looking for the shortcut not to design an apps to have a shortcut command to go to back/previous page . 

Comment: @YogiArifWidodo The shortcut to do *what* exactly?  What does "go back" mean?  Go back from what to what?  Simulator.app is just a head to a thinned down version of iOS running on your host Mac.  "Going back" is very ambiguous.  If you want to go back to the default state for the simulator device, you can "Erase Contents and Settings".  If you want to "go back" in the application that is running in the simulator, that depends on the applicaiton.  What application are you wanting to "go back" in, and what does that mean in the context of that application?

Comment: its depend on hard to use simlator to swipe the screen, sometimes touched sometimes not precise.

Comment: There is no keyboard shortcut to send a swipe gesture.

Comment: 2023, still the same. See you next year.

Answer (score 7):

I know this thread is  old, but am gonna answer, it may help some on.

I dont know about a keyboard short cut to go back to the prev screen but on my iphone 12 simulator, I am swiping from the most left part of the screen to the right horizontally. Its working.

Comment: I have tried but not work. I use iphone 13 pro max. IOS 15.2 for development apps .

Comment: Its work but the iOS didnt tell if there is no previous stack or previuos layer. I think its broken from simulator. The last tracing the problem is on code base its routing or change page has destroy the previous layer/screen lol

Answer (score -11):

The iOS Simulator just runs iOS, so the way you would "go back" in the Simulator would be the same way you do on device.  If you designed you application to "go back" with cmd-b (for instance), you would issue cmd-b in Simulator while your simulator device has focus.  If you go back with a given swipe gesture, the same gesture should work in the Simulator.